# Ruby CLI tool does not respect the Gemfile - How can I use (remote vs local) GEM's from CLI tool

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have created a CLI tool that uses some of my own [Klueless - RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/profiles/klueless) projects.

On my local machine I often set the `path` setting in the GemFile `gem "name_of_gem", path: "../name_of_gem"` for debugging purposes.

When I use this technique, I can play around with code in one of my other GEMs and it is instantly accessible from the GEM that I am currently developing.

This technique works well with RSpec, but it does not work from the `./exe/my_gemname` file.

I'm not sure what I need to include in `./exe/my_gemname` to make it use the GemFile.

[Source](https://github.com/klueless-io/k_rails_template)

## Gems being loaded from development folder when using RSpec

Uses my development folder

```bash
KUtil          : 0.0.28 : ~/dev/kgems/k_util/lib/k_util/version.rb
KLog           : 0.0.34 : ~/dev/kgems/k_log/lib/k_log/version.rb
KType          : 0.0.10 : ~/dev/kgems/k_type/lib/k_type/version.rb
KDecor         : 0.0.8  : ~/dev/kgems/k_decor/lib/k_decor/version.rb
KDoc           : 0.0.37 : ~/dev/kgems/k_doc/lib/k_doc/version.rb
KConfig        : 0.0.10 : ~/dev/kgems/k_config/lib/k_config/version.rb
Peeky          : 0.0.49 : ~/dev/kgems/peeky/lib/peeky/version.rb
KDomain        : 0.0.28 : ~/dev/kgems/k_domain/lib/k_domain/version.rb
KBuilder       : 0.0.76 : ~/dev/kgems/k_builder/lib/k_builder/version.rb
KExt::Github   : 0.0.8  : ~/dev/kgems/k_ext-github/lib/k_ext/github/version.rb
KDirector      : 0.16.1 : ~/dev/kgems/k_director/lib/k_director/version.rb
KFileset       : 0.0.7  : ~/dev/kgems/k_fileset/lib/k_fileset/version.rb
DrawioDsl      : 0.11.8 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/drawio_dsl-0.11.8/lib/drawio_dsl/version.rb
KManager       : 0.0.34 : ~/dev/kgems/k_manager/lib/k_manager/version.rb
KRailsTemplate : 0.0.2  : ~/dev/kgems/k_rails_template/lib/k_rails_template/version.rb
```

## Gems being loaded from Installed GEMs when running CLI tool

Uses the GEM install folder

```bash
KUtil          : 0.0.28 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_util-0.0.28/lib/k_util/version.rb
KLog           : 0.0.33 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_log-0.0.33/lib/k_log/version.rb
KType          : 0.0.8  : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_type-0.0.8/lib/k_type/version.rb
KDecor         : 0.0.7  : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_decor-0.0.7/lib/k_decor/version.rb
KDoc           : 0.0.37 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_doc-0.0.37/lib/k_doc/version.rb
KConfig        : 0.0.10 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_config-0.0.10/lib/k_config/version.rb
Peeky          : 0.0.49 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/peeky-0.0.49/lib/peeky/version.rb
KDomain        : 0.0.28 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_domain-0.0.28/lib/k_domain/version.rb
KBuilder       : 0.0.75 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_builder-0.0.75/lib/k_builder/version.rb
KExt::Github   : 0.0.8  : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_ext-github-0.0.8/lib/k_ext/github/version.rb
KDirector      : 0.16.1 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_director-0.16.1/lib/k_director/version.rb
KFileset       : 0.0.6  : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_fileset-0.0.6/lib/k_fileset/version.rb
DrawioDsl      : 0.11.8 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/drawio_dsl-0.11.8/lib/drawio_dsl/version.rb
KManager       : 0.0.33 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_manager-0.0.33/lib/k_manager/version.rb
KRailsTemplate : 0.0.2  : ~/dev/kgems/k_rails_template/lib/k_rails_template/version.rb
```

## Gemfile

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec

group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-rubocop'
  gem 'rake'
  gem 'rake-compiler', require: false
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'rubocop-rake', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-rspec', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
end

if ENV['KLUE_LOCAL_GEMS']&.to_s&.downcase == 'true'
  group :development, :test do
    puts 'Using Local GEMs'
    gem 'handlebars-helpers'      , path: '../handlebars-helpers'
    gem 'k_builder'               , path: '../k_builder'
    gem 'k_builder-dotnet'        , path: '../k_builder-dotnet'
    gem 'k_builder-webpack5'      , path: '../k_builder-webpack5'
    gem 'k_config'                , path: '../k_config'
    gem 'k_decor'                 , path: '../k_decor'
    gem 'k_director'              , path: '../k_director'
    gem 'k_doc'                   , path: '../k_doc'
    gem 'k_domain'                , path: '../k_domain'
    gem 'k_ext-github'            , path: '../k_ext-github'
    gem 'k_fileset'               , path: '../k_fileset'
    gem 'k_log'                   , path: '../k_log'
    gem 'k_manager'               , path: '../k_manager'
    gem 'k_type'                  , path: '../k_type'
    gem 'k_util'                  , path: '../k_util'
    gem 'peeky'                   , path: '../peeky'
  end
end
```

## CLI starting point `./exe/k_rails_template`

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

lib_path = File.expand_path('../lib', __dir__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib_path) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib_path)

require 'k_rails_template'

Signal.trap('INT') do
  warn("\n#{caller.join("\n")}: interrupted")
  exit(1)
end

begin
  KRailsTemplate::CLI.start
rescue KRailsTemplate::CLI::Error => e
  puts "ERROR: #{e.message}"
  exit 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some investigation and it seems that I need to run the command line tool using `bundle exec`

Change
`./exe/k_rails_template project`
to
`bundle exec ./exe/k_rails_template project`

## Before

```bash
KUtil::Version          : 0.0.28 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_util-0.0.28/lib/k_util/version.rb
KLog::Version           : 0.0.33 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_log-0.0.33/lib/k_log/version.rb
KType::Version          : 0.0.8  : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_type-0.0.8/lib/k_type/version.rb
KDecor::Version         : 0.0.7  : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_decor-0.0.7/lib/k_decor/version.rb
KDoc::Version           : 0.0.37 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_doc-0.0.37/lib/k_doc/version.rb
KConfig::Version        : 0.0.10 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_config-0.0.10/lib/k_config/version.rb
Peeky::Version          : 0.0.49 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/peeky-0.0.49/lib/peeky/version.rb
KDomain::Version        : 0.0.28 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_domain-0.0.28/lib/k_domain/version.rb
KBuilder::Version       : 0.0.75 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_builder-0.0.75/lib/k_builder/version.rb
KExt::Github::Version   : 0.0.8  : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_ext-github-0.0.8/lib/k_ext/github/version.rb
KDirector::Version      : 0.16.1 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_director-0.16.1/lib/k_director/version.rb
KFileset::Version       : 0.0.6  : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_fileset-0.0.6/lib/k_fileset/version.rb
DrawioDsl::Version      : 0.11.8 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/drawio_dsl-0.11.8/lib/drawio_dsl/version.rb
KManager::Version       : 0.0.33 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/k_manager-0.0.33/lib/k_manager/version.rb
KRailsTemplate::Version : 0.0.2  : ~/dev/kgems/k_rails_template/lib/k_rails_template/version.rb
```

## After

```bash
Using Local GEMs
KUtil::Version          : 0.0.28 : ~/dev/kgems/k_util/lib/k_util/version.rb
KLog::Version           : 0.0.34 : ~/dev/kgems/k_log/lib/k_log/version.rb
KType::Version          : 0.0.10 : ~/dev/kgems/k_type/lib/k_type/version.rb
KDecor::Version         : 0.0.8  : ~/dev/kgems/k_decor/lib/k_decor/version.rb
KDoc::Version           : 0.0.37 : ~/dev/kgems/k_doc/lib/k_doc/version.rb
KConfig::Version        : 0.0.10 : ~/dev/kgems/k_config/lib/k_config/version.rb
Peeky::Version          : 0.0.49 : ~/dev/kgems/peeky/lib/peeky/version.rb
KDomain::Version        : 0.0.28 : ~/dev/kgems/k_domain/lib/k_domain/version.rb
KBuilder::Version       : 0.0.76 : ~/dev/kgems/k_builder/lib/k_builder/version.rb
KExt::Github::Version   : 0.0.8  : ~/dev/kgems/k_ext-github/lib/k_ext/github/version.rb
KDirector::Version      : 0.16.1 : ~/dev/kgems/k_director/lib/k_director/version.rb
KFileset::Version       : 0.0.7  : ~/dev/kgems/k_fileset/lib/k_fileset/version.rb
DrawioDsl::Version      : 0.11.8 : ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/drawio_dsl-0.11.8/lib/drawio_dsl/version.rb
KManager::Version       : 0.0.34 : ~/dev/kgems/k_manager/lib/k_manager/version.rb
KRailsTemplate::Version : 0.0.2  : ~/dev/kgems/k_rails_template/lib/k_rails_template/version.rb
```